# error after the Intent data from adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapter

I got this problem when I get back to the main activity exactly when try to load the data intent from the adapter class

here is the code for:

ToDoListAdapter:

```
 public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();
    private final Context mContext;

    private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

    public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

        mContext = context;

    }

    // Add a ToDoItem to the adapter
    // Notify observers that the data set has changed

    public void add(ToDoItem item) {

        mItems.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    // Clears the list adapter of all items.

    public void clear() {

        mItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    // Returns the number of ToDoItems

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mItems.size();

    }

    // Retrieve the number of ToDoItems

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {

        return mItems.get(pos);

    }

    // Get the ID for the ToDoItem
    // In this case it's just the position

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {

        return pos;

    }

    // Create a View for the ToDoItem at specified position
    // Remember to check whether convertView holds an already allocated View
    // before created a new View.
    // Consider using the ViewHolder pattern to make scrolling more efficient
    // See: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
        final ToDoItem toDoItem = (ToDoItem) getItem (position);


        // TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
        // from todo_item.xml
        //RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        //convertView.inflate(mContext,R.layout.todo_item, null);

        // TODO - Fill in specific ToDoItem data
        // Remember that the data that goes in this View
        // corresponds to the user interface elements defined
        // in the layout file

        if(convertView == null){

              LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, null);
        }
            // TODO - Display Title in TextView
            final TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());
            // TODO - Set up Status CheckBox
            final CheckBox statusView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
            statusView.setChecked(toDoItem.getStatus()==Status.DONE);


        statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Entered onCheckedChanged()");

                // TODO - set up an OnCheckedChangeListener, which
                // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
                if (toDoItem.getStatus().equals(Status.DONE)) 
                { 
                      toDoItem.setStatus(Status.NOTDONE);  //Change it
                }
                else 
                {
                    toDoItem.setStatus(Status.DONE); //Change it
                }

            }
        });

        // TODO - Display Priority in a TextView

        final TextView priorityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
        priorityView.setText(toDoItem.getPriority().toString());

        // TODO - Display Time and Date.
        // Hint - use ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()) to get date and
        // time String
        final TextView dateView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
        dateView.setText(ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()));
    }
        // Return the View you just created
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

this code is for:
ToDoManagerActivity(the main activity):

```
 public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
    private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

    // IDs for menu items
    private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
        mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
        getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

        // TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(ToDoManagerActivity.this);
        TextView footerView = (TextView)inflator.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

        // TODO - Add footerView to ListView
        getListView().addFooterView(footerView);

        footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG,"Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                //TODO - Implement OnClick().
                Intent toDoIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AddToDoActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(toDoIntent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        // TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered onActivityResult()");
        // TODO - Check result code and request code
        // if user submitted a new ToDoItem
        // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
        // and then add it to the adapter
        if (requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
            ToDoItem toDo = new ToDoItem(data);
            mAdapter.add(toDo);
            }
            else
            {

            }   
            }

    }

    // Do not modify below here

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Load saved ToDoItems, if necessary

        if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0)
            loadItems();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Save ToDoItems

        saveItems();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_DELETE:
            mAdapter.clear();
            return true;
        case MENU_DUMP:
            dump();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void dump() {

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            String data = ((ToDoItem) mAdapter.getItem(i)).toLog();
            Log.i(TAG,  "Item " + i + ": " + data.replace(ToDoItem.ITEM_SEP, ","));
        }

    }

    // Load stored ToDoItems
    private void loadItems() {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String title = null;
            String priority = null;
            String status = null;
            Date date = null;

            while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
                priority = reader.readLine();
                status = reader.readLine();
                date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
                mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                        Status.valueOf(status), date));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != reader) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save ToDoItems to file
    private void saveItems() {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    fos)));

            for (int idx = 0; idx < mAdapter.getCount(); idx++) {

                writer.println(mAdapter.getItem(idx));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != writer) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the last code is for:

AddToDoActivity (the second activity):

```
 public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

    // 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

    private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

    private static String timeString;
    private static String dateString;
    private static TextView dateView;
    private static TextView timeView;

    private Date mDate;
    private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
    private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
    private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
        mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
        mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
        mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

        // Set the default date and time

        setDefaultDateTime();

        // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to
        // show
        // the Date dialog

        final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
        datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog();
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to
        // show the Time Dialog

        final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
        timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog();
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button,

        final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                // TODO - Indicate result and finish
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // TODO - Set up OnClickListener for the Reset Button
        final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                // TODO - Reset data to default values
                mTitleText.setText("");
                setDefaultDateTime();
                mDefaultStatusButton.setChecked(true);
                mDefaultPriorityButton.setChecked(true);
            }
        });

        // Set up OnClickListener for the Submit Button

        final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                // gather ToDoItem data

                // TODO - Get the current Priority
                Priority priority = getPriority();


                // TODO - Get the current Status
                Status status = getStatus();

                // TODO - Get the current ToDoItem Title
                String titleString = getToDoTitle();

                // Construct the Date string
                String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

                // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
                Intent data = new Intent();
                ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status,
                        fullDate);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data);
                finish();

                // TODO - return data Intent and finish

            }
        });
    }

    // Do not modify below this point.

    private void setDefaultDateTime() {

        // Default is current time + 7 days
        mDate = new Date();
        mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(mDate);

        setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dateView.setText(dateString);

        setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }

    private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
        monthOfYear++;
        String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
        String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if (monthOfYear < 10)
            mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
        if (dayOfMonth < 10)
            day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

        dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
    }

    private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
        String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
        String min = "" + minute;

        if (hourOfDay < 10)
            hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
        if (minute < 10)
            min = "0" + minute;

        timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
    }

    private Priority getPriority() {

        switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.lowPriority: {
            return Priority.LOW;
        }
        case R.id.highPriority: {
            return Priority.HIGH;
        }
        default: {
            return Priority.MED;
        }
        }
    }

    private Status getStatus() {

        switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.statusDone: {
            return Status.DONE;
        }
        default: {
            return Status.NOTDONE;
        }
        }
    }

    private String getToDoTitle() {
        return mTitleText.getText().toString();
    }


    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            dateView.setText(dateString);
        }

    }

    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true);
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

            timeView.setText(timeString);
        }
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void showTimePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
}
```

this is the error that appear in the logcat:

[image]

Comment: wat line is tat ToDoListAdapter.java:109??

Comment: what line do you mean???

Comment: In the `Logcat` it is mentioned tat the `NullPointerException` in `ToDoListAdapter.java:109` what line is tat ??

Comment: titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());

Comment: Well you are inflating wrong xml i guess

Comment: Make sure which layout you need `R.layout.add_todo`  or `R.layout.todo_item`. Make sure it contains the `titleView`

Comment: oh I don't believe that thanks

Answer (score 0):

As what does the LogCat output suggest, there is a problem on retrieving the correct view. In more details, you must be trying ti get an item such as the TitleView component, from a layout definition that doesn't contain it. Meaning, the problem should reside on this line:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, null);
```

Be sure that `add_todo` is the correct layout and it contains the component you are trying to get from it

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, null);
```